Помощь Python с учебником "A Byte of Python" Оператор if
Почему после ввода данных из книги у меня ничего не получается?
number = 23
guess = int(input('Введите целое число : '))

if guess == number:
print('Поздравляю, вы угадали,') # Начало нового блока
print('(хотя и не выиграли никакого приза!)') # Конец нового блока
elif guess < number:
print('Нет, загаданное число немного больше этого.') # Ещё один блок
# Внутри блока вы можете выполнять всё, что угодно ...
else:
print('Нет, загаданное число немного меньше этого.')
# чтобы попасть сюда, guess должно быть больше, чем number

Запускал через консоль -  ничего не выдаёт. Сохранялся, как TXT.Даже запуск через текстовик выдаёт:
python if.py.txt
  File "c:\py\if.py.txt", line 5
    print('Поздравляю, вы угадали,') # Начало нового блока
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 4


шаман сказал: отступ нужен, однако.

number = 23
guess = int(input('Введите целое число : '))

if guess == number:
    print('Поздравляю, вы угадали,') # Начало нового блока
    print('(хотя и не выиграли никакого приза!)') # Конец нового блока
elif guess < number:
    print('Нет, загаданное число немного больше этого.') # Ещё один блок
# Внутри блока вы можете выполнять всё, что угодно ...
else:
    print('Нет, загаданное число немного меньше этого.')
# чтобы попасть сюда, guess должно быть больше, чем number

всегда после двоеточии (в if, циклах и т.д.) нужно ставить tab или пробелы

Как я должен был об этом узнать? В книги об этом ничего не написано. И как поставить точный пробел?

@Владислав А в книге код без отступов? Точно? Если что, можно 2 пробела ставить, главное, чтобы число пробелов было одинаковое во всех отступах.

С пробелами. Просто скопировалось не правильно.

Как я должен был об этом узнать? В книги об этом ничего не написано.  Да ну? Раздел 7.10. И в разделе 9.1 об операторе if с вашим примером несколько раз напоминается об отступах
